# How can I send commands to an .exe from another .exe en c++?

Tags: exe

Basicly, I want to write a C++ program and with it, pass messages to a program .exe. This program .exe will run in background and it is going to receive commands from my c++ program. Please, if someone knows a way to do it, that would be awesome.

Comment: as Lunar said - for e.g. on Win you could use SendMessage or PostMessage

Comment: THere are lots of ways to do that, from windows message, easy but can't say much to a full on TCP/IP link. Waht sort of things do they need to comunicate about?

Comment: I need to send commands to an .exe that I cannot modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any IPC supported by your OS.